# Clear all Graphics.DrawString in form

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Maybe it's so simple, but I can't find the correct way to do this.
I've a form in which I need to paint some strings and lines (using Graphics.DrawLine, or Graphics.DrawString) in a specific point during runtime.
I need to refresh my form every X seconds, and I can paint again all that I need but the old graphics still there.

So, I need to remove, delete, erase... the previous graphics.

I'm using `DevExpress` `SchedulerControl`. Painting in `schedulerControl1_CustomDrawAppointment` event. 
I paint this strings using `e.Cache.DrawString` method.

Here's the code:

```
HorizontalAppointmentViewInfo vi = e.ObjectInfo as HorizontalAppointmentViewInfo;
if (vi == null) return;
Rectangle rConductor = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height);
System.Drawing.Font FontConductor = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8);
e.Cache.DrawString("some string", FontConductor, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), rConductor, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Most likely you are not painting in the correct location, if you where it would erase itself every time the form was invalidiated. We need to see your painting code, (heres a hint, if you need to call `CreateGraphics` to paint on screen you are painting in the wrong spot, all the correct spots provide the `Graphics` object for you)

Comment: I can't post my code right now. I'm using DevExpress SchedulerControl. And painting in schedulerControl1_CustomDrawAppointment event.
I paint this strings using 'e.Cache.DrawString' method.

Comment: The usual way is to draw in the appropriate Paint event and to trigger that event by invalidating the control.. Please add DevExpress to your tags!

Comment: Likely, the stuff that you called "the old graphics" is actually painted by the control after your code in the event handler is executed. Is not there in the event argument a property called "Handled", "Cancel" or similarly? Check this and set this property to true, if any.

Comment: Yes, I set e.Handled = true. I'll edit my question.

Comment: TaW, I tried`this.SchedulerControl1.Invalidate()`, `this.Invalidate()`, and Invalidate only the region of the appointment, with no results.